# Replace WINDOWS 10 by UBUNTU 17.04

Tags: automount

I want to replace windows 10 by UBUNTU 17.04. I made a bootable USB, boot from it but after choosing the language, I get a message telling me that I don't have sufficient space. I also disabled "turn on fast start up" option from Windows 10 Control panel, but the same problem persisted. Help me please!

Comment: is ubuntu booting in EFI mode?

Comment: Yes, ubuntu is booting in EFI

Comment: there should be an option to use entire disk for the install